Powershell regex to replace and return only the values in the string
I have a string
$vardata = " -var subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var tenant_id=TENANT_ID -var kt_subscription_id=KT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var ecr_subscription_id=ECR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID " 
I want to replace everything from "-var to =" and get only the value assigments like
SUBSCRIPTION_ID
TENANT_ID
KT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
ECR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
 iterate through the values to generate a token from keyvault and replace the values in the string with their tokens
etc
I tried
$kv = [regex]::Matches($vardata-replace '-var*[^=]').Value
doesnt seem to wrk

seems like you wanted to $vardata -replace '-var[^=]*=', unclear whats the purpose of [regex]::Matches there

I wanted to iterate on the individual output values and retrive the secrets from keyvault

@Daniel Hi, Thanks for the response , i may not be clear above but  the assignments and their names are dynamic, they may not always be the same

Right.  That makes sense :)

I think it would be best to not end up with just an array of values without then knowing what variable it belongs to, but keep the name and value info together in a Hashtable
The regex to split your string on kan be a simple one in this case:
$vardata = " -var subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var tenant_id=TENANT_ID -var kt_subscription_id=KT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var ecr_subscription_id=ECR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID "

$result = @{}  # use [Ordered]@{} if you want to retain the order of the parameters
$vardata -split '\s*-var\s*' -ne '' | ForEach-Object { 
    $name, $value = ($_ -split '=').Trim()
    $result[$name] = $value
}

# show the result
$result

to get an array of just the values from this Hashtable use $result.Values
Output:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
subscription_id                SUBSCRIPTION_ID
tenant_id                      TENANT_ID
ecr_subscription_id            ECR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
kt_subscription_id             KT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID

# you can also cast the Hashtable into a PsCustomObject if you prefer:
[PsCustomObject]$result | Format-List

Output:
subscription_id     : SUBSCRIPTION_ID
tenant_id           : TENANT_ID
ecr_subscription_id : ECR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
kt_subscription_id  : KT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID


THank you Daniel and Theo
